# QRegExp to remove the newline, and multiple white spaces

Tags: c++, regex, qt

Using the Qt framework's class how we can remove the new line, carriage return and multiple white spaces from a string.

**Input:**

```
A quick fox       run over
the lazy     dog
```

**Output:**

```
A quick fox run over the lazy dog
```

Comment: `inputString.replace(QReguralExpretion("[\\s\\n]+"), " ");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex : `[\s\n\r]+`

And replace it with empty string or space according to your requirement.

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hW7tA6)**

Answer (score 1):

In your regex search for `\s+` and replace it with single space. `\s+` means one or more white space( that includes `\n, \r, \t, \f " "`).

After that if you have leading or trailing space on your string, then trim it. Or using regex.

```
^\s+|\s+$
```

`^\s+` means space from begin
`\s+$` means space from the end.